# Integrate an web application in Drupal for processing

Tags: drupal, integration

I need to integrate my application with Drupal Web Protal. I need to fetch the data entered by the user for processing in my application. Can anyone suggest a way for that ?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Drupal 7.

To export data from Drupal in CSV / JSON / XML /... : [Views Datasource](https://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) allows you to setup a [view](https://drupal.org/project/views) (create a page, assign a URL) which displays whatever you want (content, taxonomy, users...). Then you can call its URL and fetch your JSON / CSV / XML... file and process it in your app. You can also write a small PHP script which calls this URL, write the response in a file, send it on a FTP...[Views Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) can help too (handle large data). If you need to fetch nodes individually [Content as JSON](https://drupal.org/project/contentasjson) can be handy (it provides URLs for each node which return node fields in JSON).

To import data in Drupal : [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds).

Good luck